# How to change id data type from INT to BIGINT safely following strong_migrations suggestions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I wonder how to change data type of id field from INT to BIGINT safely following `strong_migrations` suggestions?

```
Changing the type of an existing column requires the entire
table and indexes to be rewritten. A safer approach is to:
  1. Create a new column
  2. Write to both columns
  3. Backfill data from the old column to the new column
  4. Move reads from the old column to the new column
  5. Stop writing to the old column
  6. Drop the old column
```

What should be the name of new column in that case?

Comment: Based on this method you need columns with two different names, so the name is up to you. Maybe `user_number` and `user_big_number`. You will have two columns at least until you get to step 6.

Comment: @whodini9 I'm about updating `id` column which is primary key for table.

Comment: I see, would this solution work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504982/postgresql-concurrently-change-column-type-from-int-to-bigint

Comment: Reading this https://jilt.com/blog/migrations-zero-downtime-rails/ I think that suggestion from `strong_migrations` gem just missed part about renaming column at the end.